# Android Intent data fails and intent resolution returns ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

[Update:]
i know the problem... but need help to resolve this. The issue is the CONTENT_URI is not mapping to the mimetype vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.example.manager.

i create the Intent with null, and in my intentfiter i have data segment. so i guess it is not matching. So when i pass null in data, everything is good and charming!!., 
But i need to pass the content_URI and translate it into mimeType. i have a getType but i guess it is not resolving correctly. Could someone please help me out.

[Original Post]

I'm trying to debug this section with intents in my application and i need help to proceed further.

I have the main activity and some button. On clicking the button, i would fire an intent for a different activity and upon StartActivity i get an ActivityNotFoundException.

My guess is due to the data mimeType that i have passed to the activity. My Intent filter is Below

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.example.manager" />
</intent-filter>
```

This manager is initially empty and there is no table on the first launch of the activity.

In my Caller activity's onCreate() i do the following

### Caller Activity - First entry point for the app

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);       
    someButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent spawnEmptyIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, getIntent().getData());

            if(getIntent().getData() == null) {
                getIntent().setData(ManagerTableDefaults.CONTENT_URI);
            }

            Log.w(TAG, "Intent data string is " + getIntent().getDataString()); --- This is null for some reason!! i don't know why!!... it should have been set earlier right??
            startActivity(spawnEmptyListIntent); // New activity is not launched... Exception thrown
        }
    });

}
```

Error Log is

```
10-14 11:21:37.002: WARN/DashboardActivity(8313): Intent data string is null
10-14 11:21:37.012: INFO/ActivityManager(1643): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSERT dat=content://com.example.android.provider.ss/manager } from pid 8313
10-14 11:21:37.022: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8313): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 11:21:37.022: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8313): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSERT dat=content://com.mvl.android.provider.nq/listmanager }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't setting the data on your `spawnEmptyListIntent` if getIntent().getData() is null. I suspect your intent is to set the `ManagerTableDefaults.CONTENT_URI` as the data URI for your `spawnEmptyListIntent`

Comment: Yes you are right, but how do i map a content_URI to its corresponding vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.something.something. That is what is crashing the activity

Comment: Based on the code you posted, you never set the data portion of the intent you are trying to start an activity with (if getIntent().getData() is null). So that will crash your activity as well (better to fix that now then forget). 

In any case, that mime type is retrieved automatically on your behalf by Android by calling the getType(ManagerTableDefaults.CONTENT_URI) method in the ContentProvider you have registered for authority of ManagerTableDefaults.CONTENT_URI.